# UIImageJPEGRepresentation memory issue

Tags: swift, swift3

This question seems to be asked multiple times but I cannot find a good answer to my issue.

Basically the memory used by `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` does not seem to be released right after the function call but kept in memory for a while and eventually can crash the app if it is called multiple times in a for loop.

I have also tried `autoreleasepool` to no avail (please let me know if I have done wrong.)

[image]

My question is how can I `release` that piece of memory after the function call. Bellow you will find the relevant code:

```
    // let _ = selectedImages.map { $0.localSync() }
    for index in 0..<selectedImages.count {
        autoreleasepool { () -> Void in
            let _ = selectedImages[index].localSync()
        }
    }


    func localSync() -> SyncStatus {
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in:.userDomainMask).first!
        let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Images", isDirectory: true)

        try! FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

        let uuid = NSUUID().uuidString
        let imagePath = dataPath.appendingPathComponent("\(uuid).jpg")

        if self.syncStatus != .no && self.syncStatus != .localError { // self.localPath == nil
            return self.syncStatus
        }

        if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 0.96),
            let _ = try? data.write(to: imagePath) {
            self.localPath = imagePath
            self.syncStatus = .localOk

            self.image = nil
        } else {
            self.localPath = nil
            self.syncStatus = .localError
        }

        return self.syncStatus
    }
```

Comment: did you resolved this? what you did? I am facing same issue can you please help

Comment: I did not, what I did was to call localSync for each image once the thumbnail got tapped. That way I don't have a for loop to take care of.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and create an `OperationQueue` with `maxConcurrentOperationCount` set to 1. I had a problem just like this and it worked for me.

```
lazy var imgSyncQueue: OperationQueue = {
    var queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.name = "Image Sync Queue"
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    return queue
}()
```

And then add operations to this queue

```
imgUploadQueue.addOperation(BlockOperation(block: { /*sync code here*/ })
```

Comment: Thanks @Hunaid, as you can see the whole block of code is already sequential,

Comment: But I read somewhere that `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` will release the memory if I switch thread so I will try to create some threads...

Comment: No, the memory is still cumulated until some points then released. if I, however, call the `localSync` through a `tap` handler then it's okay.

Comment: Did you try my method?

Comment: Not yet, I will give it a test and let you know, thanks again @Hunaid